# Copy Files to Destination Folder if String Equals File Folder

Tags: python, shutil

Hey All I am trying to copy files in source folder ( if .xlsx) and transport them into specific folders that start (len: 5) of each excel.  I currently only have a way to move .xlsx into another folder and was wondering what else I can do to make sure each XXXXX_File.xlsx moves into folder XXXXX its named after

```
import glob,os   
import shutil

dir_src =(str(os.getcwd()) )
shortcut = '\Shortcuts to Sharepoint'
dir_dst = str(dir_src + shortcut + '\\')

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_src, '*.xlsx*')):
    shutil.copy(filename, dir_dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression

```
matchObj = re.match( r'(.*)_.*', filename, re.M|re.I)

folder_name = matchObj.group(1)
```

For example if the file name is XXXXX_file.xlsx,  regular expression will be matched to find string upto '_' and matcheObj.group(1) will be XXXXX.

For more info look here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: How can it be dynamic for all the files

Comment: Iterate over all the files in the source folder. `for filename in os.listdir(dir_src) if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):`

Comment: 'for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_src, '*.xlsx')):
           matchObj = re.match( r'(.*)_.*', filename, re.M|re.I)
           folder_name = matchObj.group(1) 
           shutil.copy(filename, dir_dst)'

Comment: `shutil.copy(filename , dir_dist+"/"+folder_name)`

Comment: ERROR : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxxx_file.xlsx'

Comment: Set your paths correctly. And check if destination directory exists before copying a file into it, if not make one then write into the folder.

Comment: it would be helpful if entire syntax was together as an explanation. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168243/discussion-between-mehul-jain-and-tinkinc).